# how do i compare values with key as row and column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to compare values based on the row values and column values. Below are the tables,

TABLE1

```
Column1  column2 column3 column4
row1       a       b       c
row2       d       d       e
row3       f       g       h
```

TABLE2

```
COLUMN1   ROW1    ROW2    ROW3
COLUMN2   a        b       c
COLUMN3   d        e       f
COLUMN4   g        h       i
```

and I have compare the values as,

table1 row1,column2 values = table2 column2,row1 values

I have 120 columns to compare with the corresponding rows. Please help.

Comment: Huh?  This makes no sense.

Comment: yea!! But, this is the requirement, that i am working on.

Comment: What's your attempt? Show us some effort and the issues you are facing in your code if any before posting. Pure "give me my code" questions aren't welcome in SO.

Comment: "...compare values..." --What's the expected result?